# JavaScript/jQuery: Running DOM commands *after* img.onload commands

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to get the width & height of a CSS background image and inject it into document.ready javascript. Something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  img = new Image();
  img.src = "images/tester.jpg";


  $('body').css('background', 'url(' + img.src + ')');
  $('body').css('background-size', img.width + 'px' + img.height + 'px');
});
```

The problem is, the image width and height aren't loaded in at the time of document.ready, so the values are blank. (They're accessible from console, but not before).

`img.onload = function() { ... }` retrieves the width and height, but DOM `$(element)` calls aren't accessible from within img.onload.

In short, I'm a little rusty on my javascript, and can't figure out how to sync image params into the DOM. Any help appreciated

EDIT: jQuery version is 1.4.4, cannot be updated.

Comment: I don't understand the issue with using an image onload handler. Also, I imagine this is a simplified example, but based on it, you should probably just be generating the markup you mean from the get-go. No?

Comment: Cheers for the response. From what I can see, calls to $('body').css aren't feasbile within img onload. (They're coming back with TypeError: Cannot call .css from null)

Comment: That doesn't sound right. Perhaps something is shadowing `$`? Does your real code use `$.noConflict`?

Comment: Oh - nuts, you're right. It was purely a conflict issue. running jQuery() instead gets $(body) inside image onload. (Sorry - not my codebase, very old, and riddled with ancient JavaScript)

Comment: There you go. `img.onload = function() { ... }` will work. The XY problem strikes again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`$.holdReady()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.holdReady/) to prevent jQuery's `ready` method from firing until all of your images have loaded. At that point, their width's and height's would be immediately available.

Star by calling `$.holdReady(true)`. Within the `onload` method of each image, check to see how many images have been loaded all together, and if that matches the number of expected images, you can `$.holdReady(false)` to fire the ready event.

If you don't have access to `$.holdReady()`, you could simply wait to spit out your HTML until all of the images have loaded by still calling a function:

```
var images = { 'loaded': 0,
               'images': [
                 "http://placekitten.com/500/500", 
                 "http://placekitten.com/450/450", 
                 "http://placekitten.com/400/400",
                 "http://placekitten.com/350/340", 
                 "http://placekitten.com/300/300", 
                 "http://placekitten.com/250/250",
                 "http://placekitten.com/200/200", 
                 "http://placekitten.com/150/150", 
                 "http://placekitten.com/100/100"
               ]};

function outputMarkup() {
  if ( ++images.loaded === images.images.length ) {
    /* Draw HTML with Image Widths */ 
  }
}

for ( var i = 0; i < images.images.length; i++ ) {
  var img = new Image();
  img.onload = function(){
    outputMarkup();
  };
  img.src = images.images[i];
}
```

Comment: Many thanks - solution is elegant, but unfortunately, I'm on jQuery 1.4.4. From what I can see, holdReady is 1.6+ and I can't update the jQuery version on the site. Sorry, I should have specified that.

Comment: @PlankTon You could perform similar functionality. Don't do any of your output from within `$(document).ready()` - do it only when all of your images have loaded. See my update above. If anything, you could start the DOM off with a message: "Loading images..."

Comment: You shouldn't use such an ancient version. **Why** can't you upgrade? Consider posting a new question and let people help you fix issues caused by the upgrade.

Comment: Re: Why I can't upgrade: I drew the short stick & had to update a very old, very decrepit site by a programmer who I suspect just mashed his face into the keyboard until a website appeared. Apart from a big soup of JavaScript spaghetti, the jQuery lib itself is monkey patched. In short, the only upgrades we'd agree to do to this site would start with scrapping the whole codebase.